# No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs

I have a **JavaEE7 application**, I'm just creating rest api, I use just pure `javax.ws.rs` api to create api.

All HTTP methods **work fine except POST.**

I'm getting error as in title:

*No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response*

it is because of `@FormParam` to handle incomming object to create it via api. I use **swagger** and this is my swagger configuration:

```
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        resources.add(com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class);
        resources.add(com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiDeclarationProvider.class);
        resources.add(com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResourceJSON.class);
        resources.add(com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ResourceListingProvider.class);
        addRestResourceClasses(resources);
        return resources;
    }

    private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        //my api classes
    }

}
```

I found that I need to enable multipart, but I'm unable to do it, I added jersey-media-multipart library to my project and tried to add

```
resources.add(MultiPartFeature.class);
```

into the configuration specified above but unsuccessful.

If I add post method like this, the fatal error is shown, without it all works:

```
@POST
    @Path("/")
    public Response doPost(@FormParam("user") User user) {
        try {
            // do something
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.serverError().build();
        }
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
```

Comment: Please show the resource class that is causing this problem. And just FYI, `@FormParam` has nothing to do with multipart

Comment: I added the code which is causing the problem. If I omit @FormParam annotation all works, is there a better way to accept object in POST method?